# URL Malformed exception

Tags: java, url, malformedurlexception

I need to make a URL request from Java.

The problem is the following :

in Java, while creating the URL I can not skip the protocol (http:// or https://) ... and in the browser I only get to access the resource if I put as address the IP (without http:// or https://).

Any ideas?

Comment: your question is little unclear, please elaborate

Comment: use http in java UrlConnection